# Instagram API - get like count on media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Good morning,
I'm writing my own library to improve skills for getting media from Instagram profile and showing it on my website.

I read a lot of articles, documentation, etc. but there are many old versions and endpoints. At the official API documentation, I'm unable to find, how to get like count or comment count on every single media.

So:

- I can OAuth - OK
- Get short-live token - OK
- Get long-live token - OK
- Refresh long-live token - OK
- Get media list - OK
- Get one media based on its ID - OK

But none of endpoints gives me like count or comment count. How can I achieve this?

https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url&access_token=

returns me:

```
{ data: [{ "id":"123456798", "caption":"My title", "media_type":"IMAGE", "media_url":"https://..." }, { ... }] }
```

I found in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/ that I can get the like_count field only for requests at media with their ID. So I tried EP:

https://graph.instagram.com/v15.0/123456789?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,like_count&access_token=

and return is: Tried accessing nonexisting field (like_count) on node type (Media).

On the instagram I've able to get likes and comments and the media has likes and comments. What I'm doing bad? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you find any ways to get the Likes & Comment count

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this endpoint for each media you want to retrieve insights

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights